# Block access to URL sub-directories with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla

I would like to block the access to certain parts of my webpage, say https://mypage.com/downloads and all sub-directories therein. Only certain IP-addresses should be allowed to access the content. The page is designed with Joomla, so the URL structure does not match the file path (otherwise I could use .htaccess files in the folder directly).

I stepped over this approach to use the .htaccess file and inserted these lines of code at the end:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/downloads/#">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx
</If>
```

Strangely, this works on one Joomla page I have, but not the other. It should both be Apache 2.2. I compared global configurations in the Joomla backend but cannot find a difference explaining why it does not work.
Any ideas what needs to be set in order to let it work? I am not a programmer unfortunately, it is only a side project.

Thanks for any help and best regards,
Bernd

---- UPDATE ---

No working solution so far. I tried also using RewriteCond&RewriteRule but I could not figure it out there, too. Suggestions on that maybe anyone? Thx

Comment: They might be the same version of Apache... But does the one that "doesn't work" have [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#AllowOverride) enabled in the VHosts file?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the order of the implemented rules is important. I mention that because you mention that you added such rule "at the end" ...

Comment: If I simply restrict the access without the IF clause it works. Also "at the end" of the .htacess file. So I think AllowOverride should be enabled (I cannot access the VHosts file directly) and the position in the file be okay.

Comment: Any other ideas? Still not solved...